# New files Log monitoring?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, monitoring

I want to install (setup.exe) a software but before I go this, before I do this I want to know where it will install and what it will be changed.

Is there a software log new files and change?

Also how to monitor a specific software what IP/address its connecting to on the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/), it has a [Resource Access Monitor](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?ResourceAccessMonitor).

For more general logging outside of a preventive Sandbox, there is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).